# MySQL - table JOIN not utilizing proper INDEX

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, innodb

I have a questions / answers table setup so that when a customer loads a product page, it asks questions about the product. To keep them from seeing the same questions over and over, I have a query that joins the answers table onto the questions table and selects the first 3 questions that have not already been answered by that user for that product.

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `question` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `idquestion` (`id`,`question`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `answers` (
    `questionId` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `productId` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `answer` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
    PRIMARY KEY (`questionId`,`userId`,`productId`),
    KEY `questionId` (`questionId`),
    KEY `userId` (`userId`),
    KEY `productId` (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The query that I'm using is:

```
SELECT q.`id`, q.`question`
FROM `questions` q
LEFT JOIN `answers` a
ON q.`id` = a.`questionId` AND a.`userId` = <userid> AND da.`productId` = <productid>
WHERE a.`productId` IS NULL
LIMIT 3;
```

This is the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` result:

```
1   SIMPLE  q   index       idquestion  306     34  100.00  Using index
1   SIMPLE  a   eq_ref  questionIduserIdproductId,questionId,userId,productId   questionIduserIdproductId   12  sandbox.q.id,const,const    1   100.00  Using where; Using index; Not exists
```

The query works fine in returning proper questions that haven't been answered yet. The problem is that this query lags out under load and even though both lines show that it's using indexes, this query still shows up in the slow-query.log when I have `log-queries-not-using-indexes` enabled.  Can someone explain to me why this is happening?  Do I just need a different index?  I have tried changing the existing PRIMARY key for answers to a UNIQUE key and adding

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

as the PRIMARY key but that didn't do anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why the productId isn't part of the questions table, not the answers table. This query looks like it would return the first 3 unanswered questions for any product...

The slow query is because of the LEFT JOIN. You are returning every row from `questions` that does not have a matching row in `answers`. This can be done using the idquestion index (because both columns you want are in the index), but requires probing the answers table each time.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I WANT to return the first 3 unanswered questions. I don't want the customer answering the same questions for the same product. The questions are generic questions that are not product specific. If they were columns in the questions table, I would have to repeat my 35 questions for all 40,000 products instead of having 35 questions and have the users answer tied to the question and product.